# How to prove $x_n\rightarrow x^*$ if $\{x_n\}$ has a subsequence that converges weakly to $x^*$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $T\in B(X)$ is a bounded linear operator satisfying that
$$
\sup_n\left\|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}T^k\right\|<\infty,\quad\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\|T^n\|=0.
$$
For $x\in X$, denote $x_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}T^kx$. Prove that if $\{x_n\}$ has a subsequence which converges weakly to $x^*$, then $x_n\rightarrow x^*$.

I'm trying to prove this proposition but failed. In fact, if $x_n$ convergent weakly to $x^*$, I can show this proposition by
$$
x_{n+1}=\frac{n}{n+1}Tx_n+\frac{x}{n+1}.
$$
But when consider the weak convergence only for a subsequence, this method doesn't work anymore and I don't know how to prove it. Any help will be appreciated!